# Convert simple json to string array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I am new to C# REST API... I am just converting JSON to a string array

Here is my JSON

```
[{"Id":1000,"Name":"May","Address":"Atlanda","Country":"USA","Phone":12345}}
```

convert array like below code

```
string[] details={1000,May,Atlanda,USA,12345};
```

Help me to solve this problem

My code

```
 public class details
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Address { get; set; }
            public string Country { get; set; }
            public int Phone { get; set; }
      }
```

This my class

```
          var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:3000/customer/1000");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(response.Content);
```

Comment: A [mcve] where the json is defined **in code** would be awesome. Be sure to specify **the exact output you are trying to generate**.

Comment: ... `int Phone` ? thats not going to cope well with leading zeros for country/area codes ...

Comment: its sample only

Comment: Do you want the JSON string to deserialize into `details` class?

Comment: No.. Json to Array

Comment: @harish then you got what you wanted.  You wanted to convert it to array, and you've said it is.

Comment: Yes JSON deserialize to array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use JSON.NET, it will certainly make things easier for you. My answer uses JSON.NET:

```
string str = "[{\"Id\":1000,\"Name\":\"May\",\"Address\":\"Atlanda\",\"Country\":\"USA\",\"Phone\":12345}]";

var listOfDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<details>>(str);
foreach (var detail in listOfDetails)
{
    var arr = detail.ToArr();
}
```

Following is the `details` class:

```
public class details
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public int Phone { get; set; }

    public string[] ToArr()
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string> { Id.ToString(), Name, Address, Country, Phone.ToString() };
        return list.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: How to pass arr as an argument

Comment: @Harish Do you want to use `arr` out of the `foreach` loop?

Comment: Yes @FaizanHussainRabbani

Comment: Is possible to use arr out of the foreach loop?

Comment: Yes, you could use it like `arr[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize `response.Content` to `details` class as shown below using the new [System.Text.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json) APIs

```cs
JsonSerializer.Parse<details>(response.Content);
```

For further information you can read [Try the new System.Text.Json APIs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/).

Comment: it shows JsonSerializer does not contain a definition of parse

Comment: This answer is using the new APIs made by Microsoft, where JsonSerializer *does* have a Parse method. However, if you're using Json.Net, you will need to use `JsonConvert.Deserialize<details>(response.Content);` instead.